# Using rerender on a page with chatter - issue

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I have a VF page which includes various text/links/etc and a Chatter feed.  One of the links allows the user to vote on some content - it is an apex:commandLink which calls a controller method and re-renders a small section of the page (specifically the voting area so that the count is updated).  That works fine - however when the section re-renders, i notice that other areas of the page change a bit (fonts are changed, and some other odd things).  I experimented and found that if I remove the Chatter feed, the issue not longer occurs.  I asked a UI expert to look at it and he said:

> When the page receives a response to that AJAX call, a completely new stylesheet is automatically added to the page by SalesForce:
>
> `common!chatterCore!chatterExtended.css`
>
> This new stylesheet overrides the `#toolbar` CSS properties established in the `extended!setup.css` file of SalesForce (which turned off that background image).  It changes the padding and adds that unwanted background image back in.

Small update: This appears to only be occurring in sandboxes.  This effort is an upgrade to an existing product which was deployed a few months ago.  It works properly in production, but I tried it in the original sandbox (which is a copy of production) - and it does occur there.  Odd?

Has anyone seen this?  Is there a way to suppress this?

Thanks for your time.